# Bootstrap 3: dropdown pulled right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have a dropdown pulled right. In my code below, the dropdown is perfectly pulled right, but clicking the dropdown is showing the options way off.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Option A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Option B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>&nbsp;<input data-type="text" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/289qdxgu/)

How can I align the options with the dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a btn-group class after form-group

```
<div class="form-group btn-group">
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown 
 <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Option A</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Option B</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zfqf9zb/)